# Laravel AdminLTE with Nwidart module menu option

Tags: php, laravel, module, adminlte

I'm trying to call a module route from an AdminLTE submenu but it says:

```
syntax error, unexpected token ":", expecting "("
```

I'm writing at the top of file 'views/vendor/partials/sidebar/menu-item-link.blade.php' 2 lines but it is probably breaking with the first one:

```
@if( !isset($item['module']) || (Module::has($item['module']) )
```

And of course in the adminlte.php configuration file I add a 'module'=>'' to the menu item.

Am I doing something wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow,

It seems there is an extra opening parenthesis in your code (the one before "Module").
Try with this instead:

```
@if( !isset($item['module']) || Module::has($item['module']) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!

It's something I hate from PHP. I waste a lot of time with simple syntax errors.

It still doesn't work, but at least I found out it's not a Module system problem.